# Trying to get SSL certificate errors

Tags: perl, validation, ssl, ssl-certificate

Hi I am trying to get SSL certificates from a perl script. The primary purpose is to check for SSL certificates that are untrusted as given described [here](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/ref/ssl/sslerr.html#1040263). However I am unsure as to how to proceed. I do not have a certificate authority that i can check the certificate with and hence even urls with valid certificates sem to throw errors. The following is the code I wrote

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

require LWP::UserAgent;
use Crypt::SSLeay::CTX;
use Crypt::SSLeay::Conn;
use Crypt::SSLeay::X509;
use LWP::Simple qw(get);

$ENV{HTTPS_DEBUG} = 1;


my $ua  = LWP::UserAgent->new;
#$ua->ssl_opts(verify_hostname => "true");
$ua->timeout(300);
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'https://abcdefxyz.com');

my $res = $ua->request($req);

print $res->headers_as_string . "\n" . $res->status_line;
```

I ran it this way

perl test2.pm >test

```
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server key exchange A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server done A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client key exchange A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write finished A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 flush data
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read finished A
```

And here is the output for the same.

```
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 29 Mar 2011 01:56:44 GMT
Server: Server
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="abc (Windows) Login"
Content-Length: 401
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Client-Date: Tue, 29 Mar 2011 01:56:44 GMT
Client-Peer: 127.0.0.1:5443
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer: /C=US/ST=Illinois/L=Chicago/O=abcdefxyz.com /CN=abcdefxyz.com
Client-SSL-Cert-Subject: /C=US/ST=Illinois/L=Chicago/O=abcdefxyz.com /CN=abcdefxyz.com
Client-SSL-Cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Client-SSL-Warning: Peer certificate not verified
Client-Warning: Unsupported authentication scheme 'negotiate'
Title: 401 Authorization Required
X-Pad: avoid browser bug

401 Authorization Required
```

Is there anyway for me to get the SSL error type of the certificate without having a local CA file. I am a newbie here and to perl, so helpful insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Install [Mozilla::CA](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Mozilla::CA), ans see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to the most recent version of [LWP::Protocol::https](http://p3rl.org/LWP%3a%3aProtocol%3a%3ahttps). This will automatically pull in the appropriate dependencies, e.g. a recent `IO::Socket::SSL` and `Mozilla::CA`. [LWP v6](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/Changes) introduced *automatic* verification of CA signatures.

You can make your own certificates, both valid, valid with CA signature and all sorts of invalid. See [*How do I create a real SSL Certificate?* in the Apache httpd documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_faq.html#realcert), [*Creating your own CA with OpenSSL*](http://sandbox.rulemaker.net/ngps/m2/howto.ca.html) (slightly out-of-date) and the [`rsa`](http://openssl.org/docs/apps/rsa.html) and [`CA.pl`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/CA.pl.html) manpages in the OpenSSL documentation.